# Python requests.get and threading with different servers

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I am working on a simple web scraper and rn trying to implement some multithreading. While my code works as intended with some servers(reducing time of execution vastly), my primary goal is to make it work with few specific ones. So when I try it with the ones in **sites** list, I get performance like I am still using sequential code. Any guesses what can cause this?

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from threading import Thread
from random import choice

# Enable to get some logging info
#---------------------------------
# import logging
# import http.client
# http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
# logging.basicConfig()
# logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
# requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# requests_log.propagate = True

sites = [
    "https://pikabu.ru/community/blackhumour",
    "https://www.pikabu.ru/tag/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B/hot"
]

class Pikabu_Downloader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url = url
        self.name = name
        self.begin = time.time()

    def run(self):
        print("Beginning with thread number",self.name, ",", round(time.time()-self.begin, 4), " seconds has passed")
        html_data = self._get_html()
        print("After requests.get with thread number", self.name, ",", round(time.time()-self.begin, 4), " seconds has passed")
        if html_data is None:
            return
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")
        print("After making soup with thread number", self.name, ",", round(time.time() - self.begin, 4), " seconds has passed")

    def _get_html(self):
        try:
            user_agents = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)', 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)', 'Chrome/74.0.3729.169', 'Safari/537.36')
            print(f"Go {self.url}...")
            res = requests.get(self.url, headers={'User-Agent': choice(user_agents)}, stream = True)#, allow_redirects=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
        else:
            return res.text

test = "https://readingbooks.site/read/?name=1984&"

def download():
    pikabu_urls = []
    for url in sites:
        pikabu = [url + "?page=" + str(x) for x in range(1, 10)]
        pikabu_urls = pikabu_urls + pikabu

    pikabu_dls = [Pikabu_Downloader(url=page, name=str(i)) for i, page in enumerate(pikabu_urls)]
    # Comment the string above and enable 2 underlying strings to get result from test server
    # tests = [test + "page=" + str(x) for x in range(1, pages)]
    # pikabu_dls = [Pikabu_Downloader(url=page, name=str(i)) for i, page in enumerate(tests)]

    for pikabu_dl in pikabu_dls:
        pikabu_dl.start()

    for pikabu_dl in pikabu_dls:
        pikabu_dl.join()

download()
```

And the result is something like

```
...
After requests.get with thread number 1 , 1.6904  seconds has passed
After making soup with thread number 1 , 1.7554  seconds has passed
After requests.get with thread number 2 , 2.9805  seconds has passed
After making soup with thread number 2 , 3.0455  seconds has passed
After requests.get with thread number 3 , 4.3225  seconds has passed
After making soup with thread number 3 , 4.3895  seconds has passed
...
```

What can cause such latency between thread executions? I was hoping to get each thread to finish almost simultaneously and to get more...asynchronous output, like with server from **test**. If I set a timeout of 5 sec inside requests.get, most of the requests wont even work.

Comment: Because requests.get itself is not able async, the function as I know will block the thread basically. Therefore you might use asyncio and aiohttp to be awaitable: https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp

Comment: Ok, but it still doesnt explain why I can reduce time of execution by several times for one server with multithreading, and gain practically nothing for another. According to your message @Tấn, I should expect either sequential execution with processor blocking threads one by one or concurrent with all threads being blocked at almost same time. Or do I get smth wrong?

Comment: The problem here is requests.get library doesn't support async so when you are trying to run them, it will block all threads to wait each performance. All you see in time reduction is simply the web response faster at that time. If you look at the thread, you always see these thread `run sequentially` with `1, 2, 3`, instead of `3, 1, 2` like that.

Answer (score 0):

After I investigated your case, I would point out some issues that you have encountered:

- Do not print when it is on parallel tasks, it will cause the bottle-neck on the way of rendering to screen
- The large of tasks are not always good for performance, it depends on how much your memory will process. Imagine that you have 1000 links, you have to create 1000 task objects? No, only place-holder for 5-20 by leveraging ThreadPool
- Server also is a problem to deal with when taking request. Downloaded size, low bandwidth, network, distancing,.. caused response late will affect your physic machine. Your sites are weight, it seems consuming 1-3000ms each request so when you test it with small size (20 links), it makes you feel it runs sequentially
- Your code is running parallel, since you do a little bit trick to put it on different threads, it is not quite right because we need a fully async library, such like asyncio and aiohttp. The aiohttp will take care numerous async requests on the `Coroutine` whereas asyncio will support syntax and operate on your main thread.

I did a small experiment on colab, please be noticed that I didn't use asyncio and aiohttp on colab because of stuck, but I have implemented on several projects before and it worked faster than below fastest method.

The second function is your implementation

[image]
[image]

```
import urllib.request
from threading import Thread
import time, requests
from random import choice

user_agents = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)', 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)', 'Chrome/74.0.3729.169', 'Safari/537.36')
timeout = 5
sites = [
    "https://pikabu.ru/community/blackhumour",
    "https://www.pikabu.ru/tag/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B/hot"
]

URLS = []
for url in sites:
    pikabu = [url + "?page=" + str(x) for x in range(25)]
    URLS.extend(pikabu)

def convert_to_threads():
    return [Thread(target=load_url, args=(page, timeout)) for page in URLS]

def running_threads():
    threads = convert_to_threads()
    start = time.time()
    for i in threads:
        i.start()

    for i in threads:
        i.join()
    print(f'Finish with {len(URLS)} requests {time.time() - start}')


def load_url(url, timeout):
    res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': choice(user_agents)}, stream = True)#, allow_redirects=False)
    return res.text


def running_sequence():
    start = time.time()
    for url in URLS:
        load_url(url, timeout)
    print(f'Finish with {len(URLS)} requests {time.time() - start}')
    
def running_thread_pool():
    start = time.time()

    # We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, timeout): url for url in URLS}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
            # else:
            #     print('%r page is %d length' % (url, len(data)))
    
    print(f'Finish with {len(URLS)} requests {time.time() - start}')
```

In short, I recommend you use ThreadPool (prefer in colab), or asyncio and aiohttp (not in colab) to gain speed

Comment: First, thanks for your replies @Tấn_Nguyên! Then a bit of comment step by step. 1) Printing here is just to measure speed of each request. 2) I totally agree. 3) Sure, that's the main reason why I turned to async code for it. 4) I've tried your code with **concurrent.futures**, and it actually worked the same amount of time as mine(both seq and threads). I've also tried **requests_futures**, **requests_threads**, **grequests** and **aiohttp**, and only the latter was faster and faster significantly, like 6 secs compared to 39.

Comment: What I find curious though, is that my code with threads seems to work sequentially only with that specific server. More over, I tried replacing **requests.get** with **pycurl** and actually got improvement in time and async! Few threads seemed to work simultaneously in pairs `After requests.get with thread number 6 , 1.7536  seconds has passed
After requests.get with thread number 12 , 1.8056  seconds has passedAfter making soup with thread number 
6 , 1.8226  seconds has passed` So I guess, it's requests method to blame or smth with routing/server. Still aiohttp works great.

Comment: @MaxD concurrent.futures aka ThreadPool you have to tune that thread value to get the right optimization basically. When I tested it in colab, 8GB RAM, nice internet is only using 50 requests with workers=15, I gained 39s, the 2 other max threads and sequence are the same 68s. I believe it is a bell shaped distribution for that and it depends on numerous of your current configurations. Otherwise, async is a best choice